# What are the leading or trailing days on a monthly calendar called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, dates

Example sentence:

> When looking at the month view of an online calendar, users can
>   toggle visibility of [whatchamacallit] days from adjacent months.

When you look at a monthly calendar, and the month begins on, say, a Wednesday, the dates of the preceding Sunday–Tuesday from the end of the the prior month are usually displayed (but grayed out). Same story at the end of the month. If you’re a designer of calendars, what do you call such days?

Comment: From a purely non-technical point of view (with absolutely no knowledge of calendar design), for the days leading into the current month perhaps you could use “**carry-over** days from other [preceding] months” or “**residual** days from" or "**remnants** of" [other/preceding months]; but I’ve got nothing for the days at the end of the current month, although “carry-over days” could perhaps also work there in a pinch. Good question!

Comment: I've come across the term "padded days" when programming calendars. If you're writing spec or other descriptive document, I'd probably refer to how they're styled, such as "greyed out" or "inactive" days.

Comment: I'd say "adjacent days from other months".

Comment: I have given this assignment in my graphic design class. When I assign the calendar design problem, it's part of a bigger concept involving forms. The/any calendar page or view must accommodate the most demanding requirements in the set to appear organized and easy to use. The "grid" pattern must look good for both February *and* March at the same time. What to put into the extra spaces has fallen to the designer.

Comment: Until a better term comes along, I'll probably call them "gray days." I like the assonance.

Comment: Actually, I like wraparound days. It's simple and explicit in the context of a monthly calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**wraparound**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wraparound), especially used in the sense of:

> an object that encircles or especially curves and laps over another

It fits pretty well into the sentence:

> When viewing the month version of the calendar online, users can turn on/off the view of wraparound days from other months.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the question as posed, but it does address Op's 'example sentence' if that is really what is required.

I suggest that:

- you do not need a descriptive term at all for such days: you can simply refer to them as "days from other months";
- "adjacent months" would be clearer that "other months";
- "dates" might be better than "days";
- "toggle" or "toggle the display of" might be better than "turn on/off the view of".

Additionally:

- I dislike "month version" and would suggest "month mode".
- Do you need to include "online"?  How else will they be viewing it?

So you get:

> When viewing the calendar in month mode, users can toggle the display of dates from adjacent months.

*[This answer was initially written in response to an earlier version of the question.  A number of the suggestions made in this answer have since been incorporated into the question.]*